# How a unitary corepresentation of a Hopf C*-algebra, deals with the antipode?

Tags: oa.operator-algebras, quantum-groups, hopf-algebras

Let $\mathcal{A}$ be a Kac algebra (Hopf C*-algebra), with comultiplication $\delta$, counit $\epsilon$ and antipode $S$.

The following definition comes from [this paper](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022123697932286) (p51-52) of Izumi-Longo-Popa :

> A finite dimensional unitary corepresentation $\pi$ is a pair of a
>   finite dimensional Hilbert space $H_\pi$ and a linear map $\Gamma_\pi
>  :H_\pi \longrightarrow H_\pi \otimes \mathcal{A}$ satisfying
>   $$(\Gamma_\pi \otimes id) \cdot \Gamma_\pi
>  =(id \otimes \delta)\cdot \Gamma_\pi$$ and the following unitarity condition: if $\{ e(\pi)_i\}$ is an orthonormal basis of $H_\pi$ and
>   $$\Gamma_\pi(e(\pi)_j)=\sum_i e(\pi)_i\otimes u(\pi)_{i,j},$$ then
>   $u(\pi)=(u(\pi)_{i,j})$ is unitary as an element in $M(d(\pi),
>  \mathbb{C})\otimes \mathcal{A}$, where $d(\pi)$ is the dimension of
>   $H_\pi$.
>   (...)
>   Let $\Xi$ be a complete system of representatives of the irreducible
>   corepresentations of $\mathcal{A}$.
>   Then the linear span of $\{u(\pi)_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i,j \leq d(\pi), \;
> \pi \in \Xi}$ is a dense in $\mathcal{A}$ in weak topology.

We deduce from the definition of corepresentation that 
$$ \delta(u(\pi)_{ij}) =  \sum_{k} u(\pi)_{ik} \otimes u(\pi)_{kj}$$

We add the assumption that $\mathcal{A}$ is finite dimensional, then $$card \{u(\pi)_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i,j \leq d(\pi), \; \pi \in \Xi} = dim(\mathcal{A})$$
and so $\{u(\pi)_{i,j}\}_{1\leq i,j \leq d(\pi), \; \pi \in \Xi}$ is a linear basis of $\mathcal{A}$ (is it true in the $\infty$-dimensional case ?).

Now, by definition of the counit
$$\sum_{k} \epsilon(u(\pi)_{ik})u(\pi)_{kj} = \sum_{k} u(\pi)_{ik} \epsilon(u(\pi)_{kj}) = u(\pi)_{ij}$$

> So, by linear independence: $\epsilon(u(\pi)_{ij}) = \delta_{ij}$.

But by definition of the antipode
$$\sum_{k} S(u(\pi)_{ik})u(\pi)_{kj} = \sum_{k} u(\pi)_{ik} S(u(\pi)_{kj}) = \epsilon(u(\pi)_{ij})\mathbf{1} = \delta_{ij}\mathbf{1} $$ 
Now by unitarity of $u(\pi)$, we also have
$$\sum_{k} u(\pi)_{ki}^{*}u(\pi)_{kj} = \sum_{k} u(\pi)_{ik} u(\pi)_{jk}^{*} = \delta_{ij}\mathbf{1} $$

From the closeness the these equalities, I'm led to ask:

> **Question**: Is it true that $S(u(\pi)_{ij}) = u(\pi)_{ji}^{*}$ ?

Comment: Yes!  Maybe look at Timmermann's book, "An invitation to quantum groups and duality.", as it's an good introduction, and nicely motivates from the analytic theory from algebraic considerations.  But what you ask is true for general compact quantum groups.

Comment: @MatthewDaws : thank you ! I looked in this book and I found it on page 71 : proposition 3.1.7 v) (e5).

Comment: The argument is just the uniqueness of the inverse of $u(\pi) \in M(d(\pi),\mathbb{C}) \otimes \mathcal{A}$.

Comment: Sure!  But _why_ the antipode behaves in this way is perhaps interesting (and, in some sense, forms the basis for the _definition_ of the antipode in more complicated analytic quantum group settings).

Comment: @MatthewDaws : I guess your *why* is epistemological. Well, the Hopf C*-algebras are quantum generalization of groups, on which the antipode generalizes the inverse. If $\mathcal{A} = \mathbb{C}G$ with $G$ a group, then for $\pi$ irreducible then $u(\pi) = g \in G \subset \mathcal{A}$. Then :  $S(u(\pi)) = u(\pi)^{-1}$ is very natural. Now in general, if $u(\pi)$ is a good generalization of $g$, how generalize $g_1.g_2$ (because $u(\pi_1).u(\pi_2)$ is not well defined) ? I guess the answer is related to the fusion category $Corep(\mathcal{A})$, but next... What do you suggest ?

Comment: Okay, I'm not sure I have much deeper to say than that actually...

Comment: Awesome! Timmermann's book page 77 : the tensor product of corepresentation operators $X$ and $Y$, i.e. $X \boxtimes Y = X_{[13]}.Y_{[23]}$, is a natural quantum generalization of the product $g.h$ in a group !